# Use builtin camera (mac OSX) as webcam on another computer (Windows 10)

Tags: windows-10, macos, camera

I have a iMac computer that serves as a second display for my Windows 10 machine. They are connected on the same internet and network, and physically connected via Displayport(Win10) / Minidisplay (iMac).

I want to use the builtin cam from my iMac as a webcam for my Windows 10 computer.

I can find tons of apps to use my phone's cam as a webcam on my computer, but failed to do the same from another computer.

I understand that this won't be possible using only the display cable (it seems I need several usb-to-usb cables between the two computers), but I can't see why it wouldn't be possible via wifi/ethernet. I tried several apps like EpicoCam which are designed to do exactly that, but using a phone's cam. I can't find one doing computer-to-computer.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to do this by

1. Streaming the camera from my Mac using VLC Media Player.
2. Loading that stream in VLC on my Windows 10 Desktop.
   Connect to the stream from your Windows 10 VLC
   http://yourmacip:1234
3. Add URL to the VLC Media source.

Or
3) Save the playlist to a file. (Toggle playlist, Media menu, playlist as)
4) Open in OBS by adding as a VLC Video source, and selecting the playlist.

You need to have right bit e.g. x64 for both OBS and VLC and it will automatically add the VLC Media source.

To stream the webcam from Mac in VLC

1. Open Capture Device
2. Video : FaceTime HD Camera
3. Stream output Settings
4. Select Stream
5. Type HTTP
6. Address leave blank
7. Port 1234
8. Encapsulation Method Ogg (Worked for me)
9. Transcoding Options for Video: mp1v scale of 0.5
10. Click Open

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c4DBj6XXpF8

You will need to know your Mac IP address, I use Synergy so I just looked at it from there, but to get your IP on Mac you can use system preferences then network, or find it in the terminal with a command.

https://kb.wisc.edu/helpdesk/page.php?id=6526

Other transport types or encoding settings might be helpful I did not play with them too much. Displaying it locally ended up causing some delay.

I could then use the Mac OS webcam on Windows 10 OBS for streaming, recording or as virtual camera.

I also tried RTP and switching codecs, no matter what I did it still was very laggy even when just viewing for local playback with raw on the mac.

rtp://@:1234

Everything was laggy :(